# React not defined when loading with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs

Given the JavaScript below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'react': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min',
            'react-dom': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min'
        }
    });
    require(['react', 'react-dom'], function () {
        var x = React;//Error - React is not defined
    });
</script>
```

Why am I getting an error in the console `React is not defined`?

[image]

Comment: You need to write like this::

    require(['react', 'react-dom'], function (React, ReactDom) {
        var x = React; // React will be defined now :)
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the modules you're importing:

```
requirejs(['react', 'react-dom'], function(React, ReactDOM) { })
```

Here's a working example:https://jsfiddle.net/remarkablemark/mejyoLk6/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=mejyoLk6

Comment: It's not a declaration. It's a parameter definition in that case. `requirejs` passes the modules as parameters to the callback provided in the order they were given. You define the identifier `React` to be the first parameter passed to the callback.